# TextViews inside ListView only shows the first word in a string with space infrequently

Tags: android, listview, textview

In a dialog I have a listview with multiple textviews. Problem is it inconsistently truncates the value after auto for some textview if I shuffle the pattern is different again. But never once all the textview displayed the entire text.

I couldn't understand why it is happening and not sure what other combination of values it might truncate. I have tried it with other values with spaces and it showed up correctly but right now it is creating problem in "auto" words only. Even tried it with UPPERCASE but still same results.

ListView layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioBtncustomerAddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Address Type"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:checked="false"/>



    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewcustomershipbilladdress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Address" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewcustomershipbillstreet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <requestFocus />
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewcustomershipbillarea"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewcustomershipbillcity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewcustomershipbillstate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewcustomershipbillcountry"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewcustomershipbillpincode"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewcustomershipbilldistrict"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

#### Code in ListView Adapter

```
holder.text1.setText("auto street");
holder.text2.setText("auto add");
holder.text3.setText("auto district");
holder.text4.setText("auto pin");
holder.text5.setText("auto area");
holder.text6.setText("auto country");
holder.text7.setText("auto city");
holder.text8.setText("auto state");
```

#### DISPLAY

```
auto street
auto add
auto 
auto pin
auto area
auto 
auto city
auto state
```

Comment: check the text view size.

Comment: texts not showing have more characters .I think all the texts having more than 7 characters will be cut off.Show your xml.

Comment: Show your layout xml file.

Comment: I was having ems=10 which I removed it and still the same. @SurenderKumar I have added the xml to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply make your inner Linear Layout width to be match_parent , its working fine then

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"<!--Set it to me match_parent-->
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: thank you very much, changing to "match_parent" worked.